# css styles won't apply when I move folder to root

Tags: html, css

http://www.tizonajoyas.com/revista
check the third block of content from the top. (it is an embeded iframe with a magazine)

Now when I move the "revista" contents to the root `www.tizonajoyas.com` css styles get broken on that 3rd block of content.

I have uploaded the extact same floder structure from `/revista` to the root and I just can't figure it out why is broken.

Comment: Check console to see if you're getting any 404s.

Comment: When you move the file, you also update the paths referring to that file in the html as well right?

Comment: Well, I don't have to. All styles are relative to its containing folder.

Comment: Try to use your browser's "Inspect" capability to see if it recognizes the CSS definitions.

Comment: It loks like it doesn't take the styles when inspecting. That's why I can't figure out what is going on

Comment: just go to file where you put code for css, & check its path,

Comment: If the path were broken, none of the styles would apply to the page. But it is only the third block of content wich doesn get styled. Pretty weird huh ?

Comment: share the code, and explain the problem fully

Comment: You are required to show a minimal example of the code that causes the problem here. A link to your web site will change tomorrow, helping no one in the future. This question will eventually be closed and deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT:

You have two different folders containing your CSS, and your `main.css` file in the root doesn't have the following block:

```
body {
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.frame-cover,.frame-cover iframe {
    width:101%;
    padding:0px;
    margin-left:-5px;
}
.frame-cover iframe {
    height:0px;
    visibility:hidden;
}
.frame-cover #frame-cover-open,.frame-cover #frame-cover-close {
    background:#000;
    height:45px;
}
.frame-cover #frame-cover-open img {
    width:270px;
    padding-top:0px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.frame-cover #frame-cover-open {
    text-align:left;
}
.frame-cover #frame-cover-open ul {
    margin-left:240px;
    margin-top:-38px;
}
.frame-cover ul {
    font-size:13px;
}
.frame-cover ul a {
    color:#FFF!important;
}
.frame-cover ul a:hover {
    color:yellow!important;
}
.frame-cover ul a b {
    color:red;
}
.frame-cover ul li {
    display:inline;
    margin-right:20px;
}
.frame-cover ul li:before {
    content:"• ";
    font-size:34px;
    color:#FFF;
    top:8px;
    position:relative;
}
.frame-cover #frame-cover-close {
    background-position:0px 6px;
    display:none;
    text-align:left;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

I copy/pasted the contents of both `main.css` files into CodeCompare to find that out:  http://www.devart.com/codecompare/?gclid=CLbN-sqzl9ICFZyCswodDUAMMA

---

Just went and looked, your CSS is being included like this:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/meanmenu.min.css"/>

<link rel='stylesheet' href='css/animate.css' type='text/css' media='all'/>

<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="css/cuss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Those are all relative paths, so it's looking in `www.tizonajoyas.com/revista/css` for the files, rather than the `[root]/css` directory. Simply add a forward slash `/` before each of those paths to reset to root!

```
<link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href="/css/meanmenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link href='/css/animate.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='all' />

<link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link href="/css/cuss.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

(I also put your `rel='stylesheet'` attributes at the end of each tag, so it's easier to read the path more quickly.)

Comment: I updated the code like that. Still no luck.

Comment: Ok, looking more closely I think I'm starting to understand your problem. My first advice is to never have duplicate files.  That's going to be a huge pain.  Keep the files in one directory and access them with root qualified paths, (paths that start with `/`).

Comment: My question, why is it only the third block of content affected. why the rest of the content  can read the styles easily. All the styles for the web are in the same files, but only third block of content is problematic.

Comment: Check my edit.  You're missing a lot of CSS in one main.css file.  Never use two files when they're the same file! This happens far too often, you update one, and forget to update the other.

Comment: Also: missing `.gatopar {  font-size:100px; }` in the `/revistas` css file.  Again, move all your CSS to the root qualified `/css` folder, and delete the `/revista` css folder, and ONLY use one CSS folder.

Comment: What you are saying makes total sense, however when I check on my ftp client root/css/main.css the "missing"  styles are there. 

But I did check the css file via browser and tha styles artent there.

Comment: Which leads to a different problem I am guessing. Shall I contact hosting support ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135979/discussion-between-seankendle-and-user2109326).

Answer (score 0):

It happened that css changes I was making via FTP weren't showing in browser, for a reason that I think I will never ever ever know.

I had to rename the main css style in FTP refresh and everything is back to normal.

Comment: That's probably due to browser caching.  Hard refresh is CTRL+F5.  Or, you can add a query string to your CSS includes for "versioning", like `main.css?v=2`

Comment: Excellent, I am going to apply what you just mentioned.